# use docker volumes in docker-compose without copying volume data to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I used docker-compose to containerize! my service. this is an snippet describing problematic container:

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
        ports:
            - "5672:5672"
        restart: unless-stopped
    redis:
        image: redis:3.2.8
        restart: unless-stopped

    worker_robot:
        image: myservice:latest
        depends_on:
            - rabbit
            - redis
        environment:
            - type_env=robot
        cap_add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
        privileged: true
        restart: unless-stopped

    service:
        image: myservice:latest
        volumes:
            - /etc/media:/app/static
            - /etc/media:/app/media
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - rabbit
        environment:
            - type_env=service
        ports:
            - "8998:8000"
        cap_add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
        privileged: true
        restart: unless-stopped

    swagger:
        image: myswagger:latest
        ports:
            - "3998:8080"
        restart: unless-stopped
```

in `/etc/media` i have many(~10^9) files and when i run `docker-compose up` and then `docker logs service_1` i see something like this:

```
...Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/Pic04_cyBs3du.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/33c4c0.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/70609.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/ywic18wrgyn2tc4edr2vy6jkq13quj0oot2deogaluuow2frwclargew_2obTa5Z.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/16-800x760_WtevBgc.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/170404.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/qd5php7wby5c1udjfbbace848oqdiqip2ebvxdv8wg1xua26iglargew.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/59653.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/Pic02_WN0qBss.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/418a22.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/vuevjnjwla3ae0l6d5nxckyajv2p2stxbkmpvmkp0xl0jeolgnlargew.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/ee8e5f.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/9-800x760_2R0bZJF.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/180249.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/lkczin6d7mtn5d8hu0qkifpokhyf1pjhov38zwkjzl06p8l8filargew.png'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/d23d91.JPG'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/5ab611.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/a9a44c.jpg'
Copying '/app/media/images/instance-image/d02049.jpg'...
```

it seems that docker is copying all files to somewhere. i need never read anything from this shared folders in docker container and just want the container to add content to them. is there a way to prevent copying this content?

Comment: can you post you Dockerfile and complete docker-compose.yml file. Mounting never copy the file.

Comment: i completed docker-compose.yml file there is not anything special in Dockerfile but it is very long 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Docker does not copy any files** and does not writes any logs to you service's logs. All you seen in your `docker logs service_1` is the output (STDERR/STDOUT) of entrypoint of your `myservice:latest`.

Comment: it is django collectstatic command `python manage.py collectstatic`. is it generating this output?